# Parse decodable struct property as any data type

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

The two structs that I am using are Scoreboard and ResultSet

```swift
struct ResultSet: Codable {
    var name: String
    var headers: [String]
    //var rowSet: [String]
}

struct Scoreboard: Codable {
    var resultSets: [ResultSet]
}
```

The issue comes with the `rowSet` property of `ResultSet`, as this is an array of any type and length, so

```json
[{
    "resource": "resource A",
    "rowSet": [
        ["A", 1, "test1"],
        ["B", 2, "test2"]
    ],
},
{
    "resource": "resource B",
    "rowSet": [
        ["2/28/2022", 1, 4, "loss"],
        ["3/28/2022", 2, 3, "win"]
    ],
}]
```

Parsing it as a string results in a parsing error. Setting the type to `[AnyObject]` doesn't build as it doesn't conform to `Decodable`

How should this be parsed?

Comment: What type do you want to decode the arrays as? `[AnyObject]` isn't that helpful, is it? How do you plan on using its contents, anyway?

Comment: I've updated the JSON in the question. Each object will have a `resource` key, and the array will be the same length and types in each position.

So if I want `resource B`, I know the array is going to be date, int, int, string.

I want to parse the array content as an object, or just parse individually by index.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense.

Comment: What about `headers`? I don't see that in your JSON. Do you need that for anything? If you don't or if that is also just determined by the "resource" key, then `ResultSet` could just be an enum with associated values, I think.

Comment: `headers` are always a string, apologies, I omitted it from the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "resource" key determine what the data in the "rowSet" key mean, I would model this as a enum with associated values.

First, create models for the two kinds of resources. Add decoding initialisers that allows them to be decoded from JSON arrays.

```
// I only implemented the Decodable side.
// The Encodable side should be trivial to do once you understand the idea
struct ResourceA: Decodable {
    // not sure what these properties mean...
    let property1: String
    let property2: Int
    let property3: String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        property1 = try container.decode(String.self)
        property2 = try container.decode(Int.self)
        property3 = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}

struct ResourceB: Decodable {
    let dateString: String
    let score1: Int
    let score2: Int
    let result: String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        dateString = try container.decode(String.self) // I'm a bit lazy - you can parse this to a Date on your own :)
        score1 = try container.decode(Int.self)
        score2 = try container.decode(Int.self)
        result = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}
```

Then change `ResultSet` to an `enum` with cases corresponding to the types of resources. In the decoding initialiser, you first decode the "resource" key, and `switch` on that to decide which kind of resource to decode for the "rowSet" key.

```
enum ResultSet: Decodable {
    // if the headers can be computed from the resource type, 
    // you don't need it as an associated value - just add it as a computed property instead
    case resourceA([ResourceA], headers: [String])
    case resourceB([ResourceB], headers: [String])
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case resource
        case headers
        case rowSet
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let resourceName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .resource)
        let headers = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .headers)
        switch resourceName {
        case "resource A":
            self = .resourceA(try container.decode([ResourceA].self, forKey: .rowSet), headers: headers)
        case "resource B":
            self = .resourceB(try container.decode([ResourceB].self, forKey: .rowSet), headers: headers)
        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unknown resource name \(resourceName)"))
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let json = """
[{
    "resource": "resource A",
    "headers": [],
    "rowSet": [
        ["A", 1, "test1"],
        ["B", 2, "test2"]
    ],
},
{
    "resource": "resource B",
    "headers": [],
    "rowSet": [
        ["2/28/2022", 1, 4, "loss"],
        ["3/28/2022", 2, 3, "win"]
    ],
}]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([ResultSet].self, from: json)
```